# How does this transformer or autotransformer work?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, autotransformer

I came across what appeared to be a transformer. Someone non-electrical said it is a autotransformer. What does this mean and how does it work?

If I apply let's say 50V AC @ 10A on terminals 150 and 0, what will terminals 30 and 75 output/be cable in terms of voltage and current?

Also what does 0, 30, 75, and 150 mean?

[image]

Comment: Are these the only wires to the transformer? If not, trace all the wires to the transformer and edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An autotransformer is a transformer with a single winding having multiple taps common to both input and output.

In other words, there is no isolation between input and output.

Here's the schematic of the autotransformer in question.

[image]

The markings '150', '75', and '30' refer to tap voltages with respect to the common tap marked '0'.

It is to be noted that the rated output VA would be available at the rated output voltages only when the rated input voltage is maintained.

For example, with 150 V being applied to the '0' and '150' taps, up to the rated VA can be drawn either at 75 V between the '0' and '75' taps or at 30 V between the '0' and '30' taps or both.

Likewise with 120 V being applied to the '30' and '150' taps.

Just as in a transformer with multiple isolated windings, output voltages / VA of an autotransformer get lowered when the input voltage is lowered.

With 50 V being applied to the '0' and '150' taps:

1. Voltage between the '0' and '30' taps = (30/150)* 50 = 10 V
2. Voltage between the '0' and '75' taps = (75/150)* 50 = 25 V.
3. The output current will depend on the load.

Answer (score 1):

An autotransformer is a transformer with a single winding and several taps. So, if this is an autotransformer, you could put an ohmmeter on terminal 0 and measure increasing resistances on each terminal as you go across. The input voltage would go from 0 to one of the other terminals, and the output from 0 to another terminal depending on whether you want to increase or decrease the voltage. The amount of increase/decrease depends on the number of turns in the winding; we don't know what that is, so its easier to just measure it. But its not clear what this device is from the photo, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure 150 and 0 are the input? Those numbers maybe the outputs. What does the text say under the 0 marking? Typically these auto transformers have a 120VAC input. The output voltages would be 30, 75, and 150 VAC in this case. The load must draw less current than the current rating of transformer. Otherwise the winding is going to burn up.

It could be some other type of device… not sure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).